# populating list collection from xml

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I have the following xsd and generated a .net class from it. I need to read the xml file and populate the Questions and Answers in the .Net class. I also need to access the SubQuestionAnswer\Question and SubQuestionAnswer\Answer nodes and assign it to qa.SubQuestions.SubQuestion and qa.SubQuestions.SubAnswer respectively.Could someone let me know if my code will work. The logic of looping through the xmlnodes and looping through the list to assign node values.

XSD file

```
 <xs:complexType name="Fatca">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="AccountNumber"  type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="Questionnaire"  type="FatcaQuestions" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
          <xs:element name="ContactDetails" type="ContactDetails"/>
          <xs:element name="AccountDetails" type="AccountDetailsBasic" />
          <xs:element name="Request" type="GeneralAccountId" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="FatcaQuestions">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Question" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="Answer" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="SubQuestions" type="FatcaSubQuestions" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="FatcaSubQuestions">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="SubQuestion" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="SubAnswer" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
```

Following is the class generated from this xsd

```
    public partial class Fatca
        {

            private string accountNumberField;

            private List<FatcaQuestions> questionnaireField;

            private ContactDetails contactDetailsField;

            private AccountDetailsBasic accountDetailsField;

            private GeneralAccountId requestField;

            private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

            public Fatca()
            {
                this.requestField = new GeneralAccountId();
                this.accountDetailsField = new AccountDetailsBasic();
                this.contactDetailsField = new ContactDetails();
                this.questionnaireField = new List<FatcaQuestions>();
            }

            public string AccountNumber
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.accountNumberField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.accountNumberField = value;
                }
            }

            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Questionnaire")]
            public List<FatcaQuestions> Questionnaire
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.questionnaireField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.questionnaireField = value;
                }
            }

            public ContactDetails ContactDetails
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.contactDetailsField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.contactDetailsField = value;
                }
            }

            public AccountDetailsBasic AccountDetails
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.accountDetailsField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.accountDetailsField = value;
                }
            }

            public GeneralAccountId Request
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.requestField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.requestField = value;
                }
            }

            private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
            {
                get
                {
                    if ((serializer == null))
                    {
                        serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Fatca));
                    }
                    return serializer;
                }
            }

            #region Serialize/Deserialize
            /// <summary>
            /// Serializes current Fatca object into an XML document
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
            public virtual string Serialize()
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
                System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
                try
                {
                    memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
                    memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if ((streamReader != null))
                    {
                        streamReader.Dispose();
                    }
                    if ((memoryStream != null))
                    {
                        memoryStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

            public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out Fatca obj, out System.Exception exception)
            {
                exception = null;
                obj = default(Fatca);
                try
                {
                    obj = Deserialize(xml);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    exception = ex;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out Fatca obj)
            {
                System.Exception exception = null;
                return Deserialize(xml, out obj, out exception);
            }

            public static Fatca Deserialize(string xml)
            {
                System.IO.StringReader stringReader = null;
                try
                {
                    stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
                    return ((Fatca)(Serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
                }
                finally
                {
                    if ((stringReader != null))
                    {
                        stringReader.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Serializes current Fatca object into file
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="fileName">full path of outupt xml file</param>
            /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if failed</param>
            /// <returns>true if can serialize and save into file; otherwise, false</returns>
            public virtual bool SaveToFile(string fileName, out System.Exception exception)
            {
                exception = null;
                try
                {
                    SaveToFile(fileName);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    exception = e;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public virtual void SaveToFile(string fileName)
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
                try
                {
                    string xmlString = Serialize();
                    System.IO.FileInfo xmlFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
                    streamWriter = xmlFile.CreateText();
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(xmlString);
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if ((streamWriter != null))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Deserializes xml markup from file into an Fatca object
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="fileName">string xml file to load and deserialize</param>
            /// <param name="obj">Output Fatca object</param>
            /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
            /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
            public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out Fatca obj, out System.Exception exception)
            {
                exception = null;
                obj = default(Fatca);
                try
                {
                    obj = LoadFromFile(fileName);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    exception = ex;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out Fatca obj)
            {
                System.Exception exception = null;
                return LoadFromFile(fileName, out obj, out exception);
            }

            public static Fatca LoadFromFile(string fileName)
            {
                System.IO.FileStream file = null;
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = null;
                try
                {
                    file = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
                    string xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                    file.Close();
                    return Deserialize(xmlString);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if ((file != null))
                    {
                        file.Dispose();
                    }
                    if ((sr != null))
                    {
                        sr.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }

 public partial class FatcaQuestions
    {

        private string questionField;

        private string answerField;

        private FatcaSubQuestions subQuestionsField;

        private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

        public FatcaQuestions()
        {
            this.subQuestionsField = new FatcaSubQuestions();
        }

        public string Question
        {
            get
            {
                return this.questionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.questionField = value;
            }
        }

        public string Answer
        {
            get
            {
                return this.answerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.answerField = value;
            }
        }

        public FatcaSubQuestions SubQuestions
        {
            get
            {
                return this.subQuestionsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.subQuestionsField = value;
            }
        }

        private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
        {
            get
            {
                if ((serializer == null))
                {
                    serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(FatcaQuestions));
                }
                return serializer;
            }
        }

        #region Serialize/Deserialize
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes current FatcaQuestions object into an XML document
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
        public virtual string Serialize()
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            try
            {
                memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((streamReader != null))
                {
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                }
                if ((memoryStream != null))
                {
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes workflow markup into an FatcaQuestions object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xml">string workflow markup to deserialize</param>
        /// <param name="obj">Output FatcaQuestions object</param>
        /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
        /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
        public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out FatcaQuestions obj, out System.Exception exception)
        {
            exception = null;
            obj = default(FatcaQuestions);
            try
            {
                obj = Deserialize(xml);
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out FatcaQuestions obj)
        {
            System.Exception exception = null;
            return Deserialize(xml, out obj, out exception);
        }

        public static FatcaQuestions Deserialize(string xml)
        {
            System.IO.StringReader stringReader = null;
            try
            {
                stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
                return ((FatcaQuestions)(Serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((stringReader != null))
                {
                    stringReader.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes current FatcaQuestions object into file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">full path of outupt xml file</param>
        /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if failed</param>
        /// <returns>true if can serialize and save into file; otherwise, false</returns>
        public virtual bool SaveToFile(string fileName, out System.Exception exception)
        {
            exception = null;
            try
            {
                SaveToFile(fileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                exception = e;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public virtual void SaveToFile(string fileName)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
            try
            {
                string xmlString = Serialize();
                System.IO.FileInfo xmlFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
                streamWriter = xmlFile.CreateText();
                streamWriter.WriteLine(xmlString);
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((streamWriter != null))
                {
                    streamWriter.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes xml markup from file into an FatcaQuestions object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">string xml file to load and deserialize</param>
        /// <param name="obj">Output FatcaQuestions object</param>
        /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
        /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
        public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out FatcaQuestions obj, out System.Exception exception)
        {
            exception = null;
            obj = default(FatcaQuestions);
            try
            {
                obj = LoadFromFile(fileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out FatcaQuestions obj)
        {
            System.Exception exception = null;
            return LoadFromFile(fileName, out obj, out exception);
        }

        public static FatcaQuestions LoadFromFile(string fileName)
        {
            System.IO.FileStream file = null;
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = null;
            try
            {
                file = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
                string xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                file.Close();
                return Deserialize(xmlString);
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((file != null))
                {
                    file.Dispose();
                }
                if ((sr != null))
                {
                    sr.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Following is the program that is reading the xml file and populating the collection

```
     XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

                   var fataQuestionnaire =  @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-16""?>
                    <FatcaQuestionnaire xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                      <QuestionAnswers>
                        <QuestionAnswer>
                          <Question>What is your source of wealth?</Question>
                          <Answer>I am italian </Answer>
                        </QuestionAnswer>
                        <QuestionAnswer>
                          <Question>What is your occupation and name of employer?</Question>
                          <Answer>Bestinvest</Answer>
                        </QuestionAnswer>
                        <QuestionAnswer>
                          <Question>Do you have a business or residence in?</Question>
                          <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                        </QuestionAnswer>
                        <QuestionAnswer>
                          <Question>How long have you lived outside of Albania</Question>
                          <Answer>5 years</Answer>
                        </QuestionAnswer>
                        <QuestionAnswer>
                          <Question>Do you return to Albania on a regular basis</Question>
                          <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                          <SubQuestionAnswer>
                            <Question>How frequently?</Question>
                            <Answer>every year</Answer>
                          </SubQuestionAnswer>
                        </QuestionAnswer>
                        <QuestionAnswer>
                          <Question>Do you have family in Albania?</Question>
                          <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                          <SubQuestionAnswer>
                            <Question>Family relationship?</Question>
                            <Answer>My parents lives there</Answer>
                          </SubQuestionAnswer>
                        </QuestionAnswer>
                        <QuestionAnswer>
                          <Question>Are you connected to the government of Albania?</Question>
                          <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                          <SubQuestionAnswer>
                            <Question>Nature of association</Question>
                            <Answer>I was an ex minister</Answer>
                          </SubQuestionAnswer>
                        </QuestionAnswer>
                        <QuestionAnswer>
                          <Question>Do you send or receive money from Albania?</Question>
                          <Answer>Yes</Answer>
                          <SubQuestionAnswer>
                            <Question>How often and why?</Question>
                            <Answer>Every month for my parents to live with.</Answer>
                          </SubQuestionAnswer>
                        </QuestionAnswer>
                      </QuestionAnswers>
                    </FatcaQuestionnaire>";

                   XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(fataQuestionnaire));


                   xmlDocument.Load(reader);

                       XmlElement xmlRoot = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
                       if (xmlRoot != null)
                       {
                           XmlNodeList xnlNodes = xmlRoot.SelectNodes("/FatcaQuestionnaire/QuestionAnswers/QuestionAnswer");

  foreach (XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
                            {

                                    foreach (var qa in fatca.Questionnaire)
                                    {
                                        if (xndNode["Question"] != null)
                                            qa.Question = xndNode["Question"].InnerText;

                                        if (xndNode["Answer"] != null)
                                            qa.Answer = xndNode["Answer"].InnerText;
                                    }
                       }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the XML serialization and deserialization methods that are in the generated class, use the Deserialize method to deserialize a Facta object from your XML, you don't need to write those XML loops.

Comment: Can you provide me an example

Comment: I need an example please ?

Comment: the generated classes have Serialize and Deserialize methods, you just have to use them.